# FuelPHP requires all tables to have an "id" column?

Tags: fuelphp

FuelPHP appears to require and id column (throws errors if an id column doesn't exist)

I this case I would like to use "master_id" which is matching the field name with an external datasource and would like to name the field that way instead.

```
class Model_User extends Orm\Model
{
    protected static $_table_name = 'user';
     protected static $_properties = array('master_id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'account','email','ts_lastlogin','ts_create'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the primary key manually solves the issue:

```
class Model_User extends Orm\Model
{
    protected static $_primary_key = array('master_id');
    protected static $_table_name = 'user';
     protected static $_properties = array('master_id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'account','email','ts_lastlogin','ts_create'); 
}
```

Comment: Just to note this is covered in the documentation http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/creating_models.html#/primary_key

Comment: And just to be complete: FuelPHP doesn't require tables to have a primary key, the ORM does.